# Append .png image to a pdf using reportlab in Django framework

Tags: django, image, append, reportlab

I'm using Django and reportlab to generate a PDF report
I already can generate the pdf, but I Wanted to append a **logo.png** to it.
these were the lines I added in

**views.py**:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image

logo = Image("/cdss/static/cdss/img/logo.png")

exam.append(logo)
```

But it isn't working, Am I exporting the Image() method wrong? Or is Path to the file wrong?

Hope you can help me, thanks  ;)

Answer (score 1):

This Worked For me....

```
def PrintImage(request,std_id):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response,topMargin=2)

    doc.pagesize = landscape(A6)
    elements = []
    I = Image('http://demoschoolzen.educationzen.com/images/tia.png')
    I.drawHeight =  0.7*inch
    I.drawWidth = 0.7*inch
    elements.append(I)
    doc.build(elements) 
    return response
```

and Call it from your URLs